# MutableLiveData<ArrayList<T>> vs MutableLiveData<List<T>>. Why should we use List here?

Tags: android, list, arraylist, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I created a library here: https://github.com/chanjungkim/ALiveData

This library is made because of `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<T>>`. Many people who learns about LiveData complains or they are confused with this type when they need to manipulate(add, remove, etc) the MutableLiveData. That's because ArrayList is easy to manipulate and `_arrayList.value!!.add(item)` or `_arrayList.value!!.remove(0)` seems to notify. But they don't.

At the end, when we want to notify, we must assign a value like `_arrayList.value!! = mList`. ArrayList and List both need to set the data like `_arrayList.value!! = mArrayList` or `_arrayList.value!! = mList`.

My question is List doesn't have add(), remove(), etc. On the other hand, ArrayList already has those functions and helps us manipulate the list much easier.

some people suggested like this

```kotlin
_list.value = list.value.toMutableList().doWhatever().toList()
```

So, what's the point of using List over ArrayList? Could you give me example with the explanation of using it?

Comment: Why not simply `MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>` if you want it to be mutable at all times? The point is in the intention, and being implementation agnostic. If you have `List<T>` you can use an `AwesomeList` for it. When you have `ArrayList`, you can't use anything but an ArrayList.

Comment: In the end, you should have a "hidden" MutableLiveData, and an "exposed" LiveData with a custom getter that returns the Mutable version. So that you can't put things in there from the consumer side. So an exposed `LiveData<List<T>>` could work with a hidden `MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LiveData` can be used in different ways, and of course there is no one correct way, but a very common way of using it is within the [Android MVVM architecture recommended by Google](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#recommended-app-arch) for use in Android apps.

In this architecture, the Activity (or Fragment) observe the `LiveData` of the ViewModel. When doing this, the goal would be to make the UI as 'dumb' as possible, where you try to handle as much of the app logic and behaviour in the ViewModel, and the Activity simply observes and reflects it on the UI.

In a case like this, it is often preferable for the values of the `LiveData` being observed to be ***immutable.***

By doing this, it limits the Activity from being able to manipulate the data it is observing, such as `add()`ing or `remove()`ing anything from it. As just described, the goal should be to ***limit the UI's ability to make exactly these type of changes.*** If the Activity wants to `add()` an item to an `ArrayList` that it is observing, it should instead do this by calling a method on the ViewModel, which will in turn update it's own `LiveData.value` to the new, updated list, which will in turn be observed by the Activity and updated on the UI.

By only allowing the Activity to observe the immutable values, it helps enforce this separation of concerns, and limits any accidental 'leak' of logic into the Activity itself.

This idea can be extended further by ensuring that the observed values are of type `LiveData`, and not `MutableLiveData`. Using the latter can allow the Activity to manipulate the live data on its own, and break the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A `List` is an interface, and defines the methods that must be implemented by any classes that would like to behave like a list. It can be considered the 'most basic' version of a list, and only defines the minimum requirements for an implementing class to behave like a list.

In the same way, the `List` interface itself extends the `Collections` interface, which in turn extends the `Iterable` interface. Each one adds more functionality to the one before it... kind of like lego blocks stacked on top of each other, creating more complex shapes.

An `ArrayList` is a class, which implements `MutableList` (which itself implements `List`). This means that an `ArrayList` can be instantiated, and passed around as an actual object. Because of this object oriented design, and according to the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), any class (or interface) can be replaced by a subclass (or class implementing the interface) interchangeably.

This is a fundamental principle to object oriented design. It helps break parts of the application down into smaller, more basic and more manageable pieces, and then grow as required.

To answer your question more specifically, if the class that is observing the LiveData only cares about the methods defined in the `List` interface, then that is the all it requires to know about the value. The actual value could in fact be an `ArrayList`, a `MutableList` or even a custom `class MyOwnFancyList<E>: List<E>`, it does not matter to the observer, just as long as it implements the `List` interface.

Comment: Well, This is not my answer. My question is not about how flexible List is but why should we use it in the LiveData. There's no reason to use customised subclass of List interface.

Comment: Hi @c-an, after re-reading your question I think I understand better what you are asking. I have written a second answer - let me know if this is more in line with what you are looking for.